# lightning-input-rich-text stopped working in Salesforce Winter20 Release

Tags: lightning-web-components

lightning-input-rich-text stopped working in winter20 sandbox release. As soon as I start typing I receive the error. The error is coming on all over the places.

It works fine previous version orgs.

My Code:

```
<lightning-input-rich-text value={draftObj.body} formats={formats} data-isrequired="isrequired" required onchange={handleFormInputChange} data-customname="email_body"> </lightning-input-rich-text> 

<lightning-input-rich-text placeholder="Enter description here.." share-with-entity-id={scFileId} value={richtextvalue}> </lightning-input-rich-text>
```

[image]

Comment: Happened to us few releases back, turned out we had an unsupported attribute which was allowed earlier. Could you edit your question with a minimal code?

Comment: Updated the question with code.